# Unable to debug the blazor wasm project when I add a javascript file

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I have a blazor wasm project with jsinterop to be able to scan qrcodes the project builds and works as expected, however i am unable to debug. I have narrowed it down to a single file, it actually happened with another `js` file for doing the same thing but I assume it is using the same code.

If i add `qrcode.js` from https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode was using minified bundle file first but then added individual files to try find problem.

I have been able to reproduce VS2019-> blazorwasm -> add qrcode.js in wwwroot -> reference in index.html

```
<script src="qrcode.js"></script>
```

Try debug counter button in the counter page does not work

Removing reference from `index.html` debug works fine.

Comment: Context: did you add the qr js before or after blazor.js ?

Comment: Did you try in vs preview?

Comment: I've tried before and after there i think there is probably something in the js that is disabling the debugging but not sure what

Comment: What is the actual issue that you are facing or trying to debug?